# Creating helper method that can be used in LINQ (EF)

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, entity-framework

**Scenario:**

I Have a table `FooTable` when column `Foo` is `varchar(8) NOT NULL` and the info in this column is like:

```
Foo
-----------
13940-00
13940-01
13940-02
13941-00
13941-01
```

Where the numeric part after the hyphen (`-`) always have two digits.

**Problem:**

I'm using Ado.net Entity Framework, and I created a class with 2 static methods to help get first and second part of the number:

```
public class HelperFoo
{
    public static string Prefix(string value) { /* code here */ }
    public static string Suffix(string value) { /* code here */ }
}
```

So now I can do something like this:

```
context.FooTable.Where(w => HelperFoo.Prefix(w.Foo) == "13940");
```

But, as you probably already know, this command line throws a `NotSupportedException`. It's because LINQ don't recognize `HelperFoo.Prefix`, so it can't convert the expression in SQL.

I can write a block of code in SQL that do the same that my methods of `HelperFoo` so I can create the SQL to my methos.

**Question**

Can I create something (class, method, or other) that makes LINQ knows my method when I executed the LINQ code?

**EDITED**

**PS**: I need something generic that works like a method or SQL function because I need to get this Prefix and Suffix in scenarios like Select, OrderBy, GroupBy and many others.

Comment: So you need something where you can search on the fields AND return the individual pieces of the "Foo"?

Comment: Yes. and that "search" can be use in many situations, without repeat and repeat code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.StartsWith` to check the prefix:

```
string prefix = "13940";
var result = context.FooTable.Where(w => w.Foo.StartsWith(prefix + "-"));
```

and `.EndsWith` to check the suffix:

```
string suffix = "02";
var result = context.FooTable.Where(w => w.Foo.EndsWith("-" + suffix));
```

Comment: Thanks `+1` but I'm need something a little more generic. I'm update the question check it out.

Answer (score 2):

You could try creating your own `IQueryable` filters for the FooTable, a bit like this:

```
public static class Filters
{
    public static IQueryable<FooTable> WithPrefix(this IQueryable<FooTable> item, string prefix)
    {
        return item.Where(i => i.Foo.StartsWith(prefix));
        // note that this should be the same code you have in the 
        // Prefix() method inside HelperFoo...
    }
}
```

Which you can use like this:

```
context.FooTable.WithPrefix("13940");
```

**UPDATE: Sadly the second option here does not work:**

Another option would be to have the helper methods not return a value but a `Predicate<>` for `FooTable`:

```
public class HelperFoo
{
    public static Func<FooTable, bool> Prefix(string value)
    {
        return (i) => i.Foo.Substring(0, 5) == value;
    }
    public static Func<FooTable, bool> Suffix(string value) { /* code here */ }
}
```

And use it like this:

```
context.FooTable.Where(HelperFoo.Prefix("13940"));
```

Caveat: I'm not entirely sure the second method would not give you the same problem though.

Comment: 1) Being a `Func`, and not an `Expression`, the query provider can't inspect the definition of the method. 2) You have a `Func` returning a `bool`, yet your method returns a `string`.

Comment: @Tallmaris the second way thrown the same `NotSupportedException`. The first method works but it's too much specific. But thank for answer any way.

Comment: Fixed point 2. About point 1. that is exactly what I was not sure about and Jonny confirmed that it did not work :)

Comment: @Jonny you already have very specific methods in the HelperFoo, you can add those Filters definition in there as well (since it is already a static class and it can hold extension methods). Good to know that it works though. :)

Comment: Thanks `+1` but I'm need something a little more generic. I'm update the question check it out.

Comment: Just a thought, but you seem to be using the fields as if it was two fields... Could a solution be to actually transform the table and actually set that as two different fields?

Answer (score 2):

With the the plethera of awnsers and you stating it needs to be more generic and you need the prefix and suffix avaliable to the `Select`, `OrderBy`, & `GroupBy` keywords, you should have the prefix and suffix in two different fields.

```
Foo Table
----------
Prefix | Suffix
----------------
10245  | 05
```

With that, you can query them individually to get what you want:

```
var resultSet = Db.Foo.Where(x => x.Suffix == "05").OrderBy(x => x.Prefix);
```

With this you can easily add a read-only property to get a formatted value:

```
public [partial] class Foo {
    //Your other code

    public string FormattedValue {
        get { return Prefix + "-" + Suffix; }
    }
}
```

Comment: this is perfect, and that was my first call, but I'm a developer, I suggested this to the DBA but he didn't accept. So now I'm trying find some way to adapt this table in the code, because in the code I can do whatever I want.

Comment: @JonnyPiazzi Why didn't the DBA accept it?  I only ask because perhaps we can aid in a explanation as to why it is better to follow this approach.

Comment: Justin thanks for helping +1. The DBA says that exists to many Procedures and Application that use this column and change this is not a option anymore, in past perhaps but now no way, and I'm new guy in project, so there no discussion.

Comment: @JonnyPiazzi I see two choice, they can split the columns and use a computed column that is persisted with the current name.  That may not be 100% bullet proof depending on how it is used.  Your other option is to use the IQueryable interface and create extension methods for select, order by, and group by.

Answer (score 0):

You could create custom getters in your Foo class:

```
public class Foo
{
    //your code
    [NotMapped]
    public string Prefix { get { return /*whatever*/; }
}
```

I think this should work.

Comment: thanks for answer but this don't work the same `NotSupportedException` is thrown.

Comment: @JonnyPiazzi Did you use [NotMapped]?

Comment: Yes I'm use, works fine when I use in many places, but when I'm using in an `IQueryable<>` for LINQ to Entities throws `NotSupportedException`.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot filter your database selection based on a custom function - as you say, it cannot convert this to SQL.

For this specific problem, I could propose you use the StartsWith function, which does work on SQL server

```
context.FooTable.Where(w => w.Foo.StartsWith("13940"));
```

Comment: Your code would match 1239406-00, whereas his code would not.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Microsoft.Linq.Translations`.

It would look something like this:

```
partial class FooTable 
{
    private static readonly CompiledExpression<FooTable,string> prefixExpression
            = DefaultTranslationOf<FooTable>.Property(e => e.Prefix).Is(e => e.Foo.Substring(0, 5));

    public string Prefix
    {
        get { return prefixExpression.Evaluate(this); }
    }
}
```

And queried like:

```
context.FooTable.Where(w => w.Prefix == "13940").WithTranslations();
```

[Nuget gallery page](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Linq.Translations)

[Documentation](http://damieng.com/blog/2009/06/24/client-side-properties-and-any-remote-linq-provider)

**EDIT**: This solution works in Select, GroupBy, OrderBy.